Why do we need $X\in\mathcal{T}$ for topologies?
A topology is defined as a class $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of a set $X$ which is closed under arbitrary unions, finite intersection, and such that $X\in\mathcal{T}$. If we study topology, we can note that the first two properties are very important. But based on what I have studied in topology so far, I haven't seen why the last axiom $X\in\mathcal{T}$ is necessary. So that's my question, why do we need that property to characterize topological spaces? For example, $\sigma$-algebras also satisfy that property, and for them it is necessary because in order to define a probability measure we need $X$ to be an event.
The closure under finite intersections is equivalent to $X\in\mathcal{T}$ and closed under pairwise intersections. If we use only pairwise intersections, and we don't ask $X\in\mathcal{T}$ for a topological space, does the theory change?

If $X\notin \mathcal T$, then you’re working with a topology on a proper subset of $X$, are you not?
